# Pass CString to fprintf

Tags: c++, mfc, portability, cstring, printf

I have ran the code analyzer in visual studio on a large code base and i got about a billion of this error:

```
warning C6284: Object passed as parameter '3' when string is required in call to 'fprintf'
```

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ta308ywy.aspx "This defect might produce incorrect output or crashes." My colleague however states that we can just ignore all these errors without any problems. So one of my questions is do we need to do anything about this or can we just leave it as is?

If these errors need to be solved what is the nicest approach to solve it?

Would it work to do like this:

```
static_cast<const char*>(someCString)
```

Is there a better or more correct approach for this?

The following lines generate this warning:

```
CString str;
fprintf(pFile, "text %s", str);
```

Comment: Show us one of the call sites that gives this warning, with the complete declaration of the variables involved.

Comment: Have you looked into the member method `GetBuffer(int minBufferLength )`? It returns a null-terminated `LPSTR` which I believe is basically the same as `char*`, it is not `const`, however.  Read more here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314880(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Supported by MS or not, this is a terrible practice and I'd PiP your colleague for promoting it. I've yet to see anything from MS that *specifically* says doing this is all well and good, and in fact their docs specifically say to cast to `LPCTSTR` to trigger the cast operator. Their implementation "supports" it; woot for them. The language standard trumps them whether they care to acknowledge that or not. If there is a subsection of the standard that indicates this as compliant I've yet to see it.

Comment: What do you think about the [`GetString()` method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21701463/2932052), suggested by @xMRi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're passing a Microsoft "CString" object to a printf()-family function where the corresponding format specifier is `%s`.  If I'm right, then your answer is here: [How can CString be passed to format string %s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608942/how-can-cstring-be-passed-to-format-string-s) (in short, your code is OK).

It seems that originally an implementation detail allowed CString to be passed directly to printf(), and later it was made part of the contract.  So you're good to go as far as your program being correct, but if you want to avoid the static analysis warning, you may indeed need to use the static_cast to a char pointer.  I'm not sure it's worth it here...maybe there's some other way to make these tools place nice together, since they're all from Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

Following the MSDN suggestions in [C6284](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ta308ywy.aspx), you may *cast the warnings away*. Using C++ casts will be the most maintainable option to do this. Your example above would change to

```
fprintf(pFile, "text %s", static_cast<const TCHAR*>(str));
```

or, just another spelling of the same, to

```
fprintf(pFile, "text %s", static_cast<LPCTSTR>(str));
```

**The most convincing option** (*100% cast-free*, see *Edits* section) is

```
fprintf(pFile, "text %s", str.GetString());
```

Of course, following any of these **change** patterns will be a first porting step, and if nothing indicates a need for it, this **may be harmful** (not only for your team atmosphere).

---

**Edits:** (according to the comment of xMRi)

1) I added `const` because the argument is read-only for fprintf

2) notes to the cast-free solution [CSimpleStringT::GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59cayc6.aspx): the `CSimpleStringT` class template is used for the definition of `CStringT` which again is used to typedef the class `CString` used in the original question

3) reworked answer to remove noise.

4) reduced the intro about the casting option

Comment: Why should i cast to TCHAR* instead of using GetBuffer()?

Comment: To sum it up, if we are considering porting the system we need to do something about the errors. But if I just want to get rid of the warnings you can cast it to TCHAR*?

Comment: @k4rlsson (1) As I understand it, `GetBuffer()` allocates memory that has to be released by a call of the `ReleaseBuffer()` method This may also performance-relevant. (2) If the cast makes the analysis tool's warning go away (I cannot check this), I'd use it. This is also a good opportunity to review if all of the billion warnings are really the same.

Comment: Casting and using GetBuffer() both removes the warning. Billions may have been exaggerated but it's ~2500 :)

Comment: @k4rlsson I now [read something](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/542/CString-Management) about `GetBuffer()` (with no argument which means 0) and it seems to do (nearly!) the same... The cast does definitely not consume any CPU time.

Comment: At the moment I am considering the cast just to get rid of the warnings.

Comment: But it is not allowed to cast a CString to a TCHAR*. It is only save to use GetBuffer. Only GetBuffer is a save way to get a TCHAR* from a CString. In the code shown here it doesn't make sense either, because a const TCHAR* is fully sufficient. Also GetBuffer allocates nothing if the CString is only used by one instance. Ig used more than once it uses Copy on Write and duplicates the contents. Also there is CString::GetString that does everything you need.

Comment: @xMRi can you please give also a link to the method reference? I found this `CString::GetString` tip more than once ([1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/Ao-A8D1-JT0/QxAOuLQico8J), [2](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?520947-MFC-How-to-pass-CString-to-Windows-API-functions&p=2054539#post2054539)), but no official ref.

Comment: @xMRi This I already found, but it's [CSimpleStringT::GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59cayc6.aspx) - I searched for the relationship between `CString` and `CSimpleStringT`, but I wasn't successful.

Comment: That is simply a base template. CString is a typedef to CStringT, that derives from CSimpleStringT. Did you ever looked into the definitions of this class?

Comment: @sMRi Sorry no, I'm from the BCB planet; So I'd better keep away from VC questions... ...but so I learn something new. Thanks for your time.

Comment: +1 for `GetString`. It is correct, simple, and easy to read/understand.

Comment: Although casting to LPCTSTR sounds less efficient, CSimpleStringT::GetString and static_cast<LPCTSTR> both do the exact same thing: they simply return m_pszData from the CString.  See VC\atlmfc\include\atlsimpstr.h, method GetString and operator PCXSTR() const.  You can view the Disassembly window in the Visual Studio debugger and step into the call to each ATL function to verify they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking it is ok because the c-string is stored in such a way in CString that you can use it as stated but it is not good rely on how CString is implemented to do a shortcut. printf is a C-runtime function and knows nothing about C++ objects but here one is relying on an that the string is stored first in the CString - an implementation detail.

If I recall correctly originally CString could not be used that way and one had to cast the CString to a c-string to print it out but in later versions MS changed the implementation to allow for it to be treated as a c-string.

Another breaking issue is UNICODE, it will definitely not work if you one day decide to compile the program with UNICODE character set since even if you changed all string formatters to %ld, embedded 0s will sometimes prevent the string from being printed.

The actual problem is rather why are you using printf instead of C++ to print/write files?

Comment: Some of this code dates up to ~25 years back in time, replacing the printf is not an option here.

Comment: I know the feeling :o) vår kod är från -83