# Expanding container to parameter pack

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Let's say I have a variadic function I can't change like so:

```
void Func(int count, ...)
{ /*etc.*/ }
```

And I'm writing a variadic template like so to wrap that function and make it safer to use:

```
template<typename... T>
void ToString(T... args)
{
    std::vector<CString> vstrArgs = { args... };
    Func(sizeof...(args), args...);
}
```

So my template verifies that each argument can be converted to a CString.
I want to do more than that however, I want to convert each argument to a CString and then pass those CStrings to Func(), instead of just passing on the original arguments.

What's the fastest and/or neatest way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Possibly store the args parameter pack into a std::tuple and iterate over the tuple like here, checking that it can be converted and doing what you want : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198260/iterate-over-tuple

Comment: BTW, You should not pass arguments of non-POD type to VARARG'd functions. Even if [how-can-cstring-be-passed-to-format-string-s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608942/how-can-cstring-be-passed-to-format-string-s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<typename... T>
void ToString(T... args)
{
    Func(sizeof...(args), ConvertToCString(args)...);
}
```

Where `ConvertToCString` is the function that converts any element to a CString. If the constructor is enough, then `CString(args)...` will work. `static_cast<CString>(args)...` would also work.

You can look at "Pack expansion" from [parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Comment: You may omit the `vector` and use `std::forward<T>(args)`.

Comment: @Jarod42: that's true