# ReSharper C++: Allow CString as a %s printf parameter?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper

Anybody know of a way to disable the ReSharper inspection for CStrings passed directly as %s parameters?

```
CString s = "some string";
printf("string = %s", s);
```

ReSharper reports "Invalid printf format specifier", which is technically correct but this syntax is supported by MS, and used extensively in the code base I work with.

I suspect there isn't a way to filter out only this specific invalid format specifier case, but I thought I'd throw it out there anyway in hopes that I've missed something.

Comment: `%s` expects C-style null terminated string. Strings in `CString` are not followed by that character in memory, so you cannot use it in that simply way. Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288.aspx)

Comment: @Fureeish You absolutely can use it that way, but that's not what the question is about. For discussion of using CString in printf-family functions read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608942/how-can-cstring-be-passed-to-format-string-s).

Comment: To be clear, I'm not advocating for using this technique. It actually gives me hives just to look at it, but I'm stuck with it for now.

Comment: This seems like a very, very specific exception you're asking for. Presumably passing a `CString` to `%d` is still bad, as is passing a `std:;string` to `%s`. So, if such a narrow exception existed, it should have been trivial to find it, from which we can conclude that no such option exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll change the inspection to allow passing CString to corresponding string format specifiers, please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-20109.