# Passing a class with conversion function for const char* through a variadic function like printf

Tags: c++, function, methods, variadic

I have a class SpecialString. It has an operator overload / conversion function it uses any time it's passed off as a const char*. It then returns a normal c-string.

```
class SpecialString
{
...
operator char* () const { return mCStr; }
...
};
```

This used to work a long time ago (literally 19 years ago) when I passed these directly into printf(). The compiler was smart enough to know that argument was meant to be a char* and it used the conversion function, but the now g++ complains.

```
SpecialString str1("Hello"), str2("World");
printf("%s %s\n", str1, str2);
```

**error: cannot pass object of non-POD type 'SPECIALSTRING' (aka 'SpecialString') through variadic method; call will abort at runtime [-Wnon-pod-varargs]**

Is there any way to get this to work again without changing the code? I can add a deref operator overload function that returns the c-string and pass the SpecialString objects around like this.

```
class SpecialString
{
...
operator CHAR* () const { return mCStr; }
char* operator * () const { return mCStr; }
...
};
```

```
SpecialString str1("Hello"), str2("World");
printf("%s %s\n", *str1, *str2);
```

But I'd prefer not to because this requires manually changing thousands of lines of code.

Comment: I can almost guarantee you that "The compiler was smart enough to know that argument was meant to be a char* and it used the conversion function" is a misinterpretation of what the compiler was doing.

Comment: Have you tried to compile it with option `-Wnon-pod-varargs` ?

Comment: This never officially worked. You got away with some undefined behaviour. Sometimes you do. Sometimes you don't.

Comment: g++ will check your printf/sprintf arguments, if you're trying to pass a char* into a %d etc. It was just a feature compilers had back then that wasn't in the C spec. It worked on Windows Visual Studio, g++/Linux, and CodeWarrior on the Mac (pre OS X days). I think they pulled it out because it's not in the spec.

Comment: @user4581301 He's simply overloading the dereference operator, since there's no other way that dereference could be interpreted (since he is trying to dereference something that is not a pointer), I don't see how that is undefined behavior, if it compiles it should work.

Comment: @Havenard, Passing the wrong type to `printf` is UB.

Comment: @chris He's passing an expression that returns a `char*`, how is that passing the wrong type?

Comment: Yeah @Havenard is right. I was just getting lucky that compilers back then let you do this. Was hoping there's a way to get them to do it again. Also, compiling with -Wno-non-pod-varargs aborts just like the error messages says it will.

Comment: @Havenard They're passing an lvalue of type `SpecialString`. That's the wrong type.

Comment: The deref version works just fine, but I don't see `printf("%s %s\n", str1, str2);` causing the call operator to kick in.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I didn't read the question correctly. I thought the version with deref was the code he was using.

Comment: Maybe `mCStr` just happens to have the same address as the object. That'll allow printf to get the `char *` it wants, but it's sorta-brittle.  What's making `SpecialString` non-POD? Maybe we can attack it from another direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the warning, if you don't want to be informed about it... but that's a bad idea.

The behaviour of the program is undefined, you should fix it and that requires changing the code. You can use the exising conversion operator with `static_cast`, or you can use your unary `*` operator idea, which is going to be terser.

Even less change would be required if you used unary `+` instead which doesn't require introducing an overload, since it will invoke the implicit conversion instead. That may add some confusion to the reader of the code though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to modify the existing code, you can write a "hack" instead. More specifically, a bunch of overloads to `printf()` that patch the existing code.

For example:

```
int printf(const char* f, const SpecialString& a, const SpecialString& b)
{
    return printf(f, (const char*)a, (const char*)b);
}
```

With this function declared in your header, every call to `printf()` with those specific parameters will use this function instead of the "real" `printf()` you're familiar with, and perform the needed conversions.

I presume you have quite a few combinations of `printf()` calls in your code envolving `SpecialString`, so you may have to write a bunch of different overloads, and this is ugly af to say the least but it does fit your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another comment, it has always been undefined behavior that happens to work in your case.

With Microsoft `CString` class, it seems like the undefined behavior was so used (as it happen to work), that now the layout is defined in a way that it will still works. See [How can CString be passed to format string %s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608942/how-can-cstring-be-passed-to-format-string-s).

*In our code base, I try to fix code when I modify a file to explicitly do the conversion by calling `GetString()`*

There are a few things you could do:

- **Fix existing code everywhere you get the warning**.

  > In that case, a named function like `c_str` or `GetString` is preferable to a conversion operator to avoid explicit casting (for ex. `static_cast` or even worst C-style case `(const char *)`. The `deref` operator might be an acceptable compromise.
- Use some formatting library

  - `<iosteam>`
  - fmt: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt
  - many other choices (search **C++ formatting library** or something similar)
- Use variadic template function so that conversion could be done.
- If you only use a few types (int, double, string) and rarely more than 2 or 3 parameters, defining overloads might also be a possibility.
- **Not recommended:** Hack your class to works again.

  > - Have you done any change to your class definition that cause it to break or only upgrade the compiler version or change compiler options?
  > - Such hack is working with undefined behavior so you must figure out how your compiler works and the code won't be portable.
  > - For it to works the class must have the size of a pointer and the data itself must be compatible with a pointer. Thus essentially, the data must consist of a single pointer (no v-table or other stuff).

**Side note:** I think that one should avoid defining its own string class. In most case, standard C++ string should be used (or string view). If you need additional functions, I would recommend your to do write stand-alone function in a namespace like `StringUtilities` for example. That way, you avoid converting back and forth between your own string and standard string (or some library string like MFC, Qt or something else).